# How do bitsets really work

Tags: c++, bitset

I was working on an SRT simulator and I was using `std::bitset<size>`s in my implementation. I thought I understood them pretty well until I did this:

```
template <unsigned int larger, unsigned int smaller>
    bitset<smaller> Partition(const bitset<larger> &original, unsigned int offset) {
        return bitset<smaller>(original.to_ulong() >> offset);
    }

template <unsigned int larger, unsigned int smaller>
    void Partition(bitset<larger> &location, const bitset<smaller> &value, unsigned int offset) {
        location <<= offset;
        location ^= bitset<larger>(value.to_ulong());
        return;
    }
```

The first function is designed to take a longer number, and partition a particular number of bits into a shorter number. As an example, if I have `10111010` and I only wanted `1011` in a `std::bitset<4>` then I would call `Partition<8, 4>(my_larger_number, 4);`. The second does the opposite. I can take a shorter number and turn it into a longer number. Both of these functions work as expected, until:

```
int main() {
    bitset<16> A("1011101010011000");
    cout << "A = " << A << endl;
    bitset<4> Bs[4];
    bitset<16> C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Bs[i] = Partition<16, 4>(A, 4 * i);
        cout << "B[" << i << "] = " << Bs[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << "Value of B[" << i << "] = " << bitset<16>(Bs[i].to_ulong()) << endl;
        Partition<16, 4>(C, Bs[i], 4);
        cout << "C = " << C << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this operation is:

```
A = 1011 1010 1001 1000
B[0] = 1000
B[1] = 1001
B[2] = 1010
B[3] = 1011
Value of B[3] = 0000 0000 0000 1011
C = 0000 0000 0000 1011
Value of B[2] = 0000 0000 1011 1010
C = 0000 0000 0000 1010
Value of B[1] = 0000 1011 1010 1001
C = 0000 1011 0000 1001
Value of B[0] = 1011 1010 1001 1000
C = 0000 1010 0000 1000
```

Essentially, what is happening is that the bitsets are somehow saving the extra bits of information even after they've been made shorter and then they're being pushed back onto `C` with every call of `Partition<16, 4>(C, Bs[i], 4)`. But, my question is, why? These values shouldn't be conserved in memory and even if they were, I'm creating new objects every time I call `Bs[i] = Partition<16, 4>(A, i * 4)` so these values shouldn't be showing up.

Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You should post a (minimal) complete program that demonstrates the behavior that surprises you, rather than fragments. Notably, you don't demonstrate how you are printing the output. The sample output suggests that code is buggy.

Comment: I get different results when running your code with VS2015: http://pastebin.com/F1WGPA1D

Comment: "bitsets are saving extra bits even after they've been made shorter". Bitsets can't be made shorter. A bitset which contains 16 bits will always contain 16 bits. The length is part of their static type. Use `std::vector<bool>` for a bit-sequence of variable length. On a related note, your code will fail for bigger bitsets when `to_ulong` runs out of bits.

Comment: @Hurkyl It has been edited to show the output lines. I hope that makes it more clear for you

Comment: @SimonKraemer What results are you getting? I'm running mine with Xcode's version of g++, not that I'm proud to admit that. It could be one of Apple's idiotic homebrew differences

Comment: @MSalters Read my `Partition` functions. Their point is to convert a `bitset` from a larger size to a smaller size and vice versa. Also, for your related note. How then should I avoid the failure? Should I static cast?

Comment: @Woody1193 I posted a link to a pastebin with my output in my last comment.

Comment: @SimonKraemer That's the correct output, actually. Did you have to change any of the code?

Comment: @Woody1193 I only added some `cout`s http://pastebin.com/L2LGBDQq

Comment: Can you run it on a different compiler?  I don't have Xcode's g++, so I can't duplicate the problem.  I'm getting the same result as Simon.  (Or is the problem solved?)

Comment: Copy pasting your updated code into `ideone` (and adding the needed include lines), I get the same results as @Simon does.

Comment: What happens if you write a test case for your assumed behavior? e.g. just write a program that does nothing but construct a `bitset` (using an overly large integer value), converts it back to ulong and prints the result?

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, it does that correctly. The problem occurs when I convert the initial `bitset<16>` into a `bitset<4>`. I'll update my example to show this. I thought it was common to all bitsets but it looks like it's just Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments to my original post, I discovered that the problem lies not with the C++ implementation of `std::bitset` but rather some strange phenomenon in Xcode g++, which I used to compile it. To fix this, I created an altered version of `Partition`:

```
template <unsigned int larger, unsigned int smaller>
    bitset<smaller> Partition(const bitset<larger> &original, unsigned int offset) {
        bitset<smaller> newValue(0);
        newValue = ((original >> offset) & bitset<larger>((1 << smaller) - 1)).to_ulong();
        return newValue;
    }
```

In essence, all I'm doing is masking the first `smaller` bits and then making the others 0. I'd prefer not to do this because it adds complexity but it seems like the only solution available without figuring out how Xcode does this.

Comment: I suspect this points to a bug with the masking off of high bits. According to spec, the `std::bitset<N>` constructor from `unsigned long` should store only the lower `N` bits. Now there are no 4 bit objects in C++ so the extra bits have to be explicitly masked off, but I could imagine this being a bug. Easiest test would be `std::cout << std::bitset<4>(31UL).to_ulong()`

Comment: You're probably right. At any rate, explicitly masking the extra bits does the trick